# Update Inner text value of XML node with temp variable in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

```
<metadata>
  <layout>8</layout>
  <maxScore>7</maxScore>
</metadata>
```

I do want to replace value of `<maxscore>` for multiple records in a table whose column is XML type. And `<maxscore>` replace value is received in a temp variable as @MaxReplace.

Tried as below.

```
DECLARE @MaxReplace as NVARCHAR(10)
SET @MaxReplace='1'     
Update dbo.SCORETBALE
SET [XML].modify('replace value of (/ns:metadata/ns:maxScore)[1] with "@MaxReplace "')
  FROM  dbo.XYZ...(condition)...
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to select element first and bind value from variable using `sql:variable(...)` :

```
CREATE TABLE #SCORETBALE(col XML);

INSERT INTO #SCORETBALE(coL)
VALUES ('<metadata>
  <layout>8</layout>
  <maxScore>1</maxScore>
  </metadata>');

DECLARE @MaxReplace AS NVARCHAR(10) = '22';

UPDATE #SCORETBALE
SET col.modify('replace value of (/metadata/maxScore/text())[1] 
                with sql:variable("@MaxReplace")')
-- WHERE ...

SELECT *
FROM #SCORETBALE;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/409578)**</kbd>